# How do I make parent taxonomy paths?

Tags: 8, entities, path-aliases, tokens

I installed Pathauto, Tokens and Entity API module in Drupal 8 and I have been unable to create a pattern that would allow parent taxonomies and then the final node for content type pages. In Drupal 7 the entity API module would add the extra tokens I need but it does not seem to work for Drupal 8.

For Drupal 8 the token [term:parents:join-path] works but it is only usable for taxonomy type pages and not content type pages.

If anybody can help me,I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is being worked on, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2493559 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2621598.

In the meantime, you need a bit of custom code to connect the dots. You need to implement `hook_token_info()`to define a token on nodes for your field with type term. You can also switch the type of the generated field token to term. The second part is a `hook_tokens()` implementation that forwards [node:yourtokenname:...].

It's similar to what [node_tokens()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.tokens.inc/function/node_tokens/8.2.x) does with node:author:name for example, which forwards the part after author to the user token generation:

```
if ($term_tokens = $token_service->findWithPrefix($tokens, 'yourtokenname')) {
  $replacements += $token_service->generate('term', $term_tokens, array('term' => $node->field_yourfieldname->entity), $options, $bubbleable_metadata);
}
```

Comment: where does this hook go? in the .template inside the themes folder? or do i need to create a custom module and import the token module files?

Comment: You don't need to import any files, but yes, you need a custom module. A few special hooks can be implemented in themes too (in .theme, not .template, that doesn't exist) but in general, you need a module.